# How to display categories in magento?

Tags: category, custom-attributes

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
            $category->addAttributeToFilter("Top_Menu" , array('eq' => '146'));
            $category->addAttributeToFilter("entity_id" , array('eq' => $catId));
            $category->load();
            $category->getName();
```

When I use this code i get this error

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat_Collection::getName()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A category collection is a collection of category objects.Therefore the category collection has no name. If you would like to get the first category from the category collection you can use the following method.

```
$category->getFirstItem()->getName();
```

However it seems like you don't need a collection for what you are trying to achieve. So I'd suggest you just use the loadByAttribute() method. See below

```
// Load by attribute value
$categoryWithTopMenuId146 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->loadByAttribute("Top_Menu","146");

// Get name
$categoryWithTopMenuId1460->getName();
```